# Set values in Angular2 FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to set values in FormGroup. My angular version is rc-5. Here is my component;

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
     templateUrl: 'myHtmlPage.html',
     providers: [
          UserService
     ]
})

export class UserDetailComponent implements OnInit {
     user: User;
     userDetailForm: FormGroup;

     constructor(private userService: UserService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
          this.userDetailForm = this.formBuilder.group({
               email: new FormControl('', [<any>Validators.required])
          });
     }

     getUser(id: number) {
         this.userService.getById(id)
             .subscribe((res) => { this.user = res.data; }, /*do stg*/, () => { this.userDetailForm.controls['email'].setValue(this.user.email); });
     }

     ngOnInit() {
         let id;
         this.route.params.subscribe(params => id = +params['id']);
         this.getUser(id);
     }

     //...
}
```

And here it is my html;

```
<form [formGroup]="userDetailForm" (ngSubmit)="editUser(userDetailForm.value)">
<div class="card card-inverse col-md-6 offset-md-3" style="background-color: #333; border-color: #333;">
    <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title row">
            Details
        </h4>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div>
                <label for="email" class="card-subtitle">Email</label>
                <div>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="email" formControlName="email" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My 'User' class;

```
export class User {
     email: string;
}
```

There is no problem with this code, it works properly. But what if I want to add some properties to 'User' class? Should I set value everytime like this in 'onCompleted' callback? When I move code from constructor to 'onCompleted' callback of subscribe, I get following error:

```
form group expects a form group instance. please pass one in
```

When I move code from constructor to 'ngOnInit' method, it cannot get value of `this.user.email` since subscribe works async. Is there anyone to help me?

Comment: this.form=this.formBuilder.group({email='a@a.com' //and then other properties})

Comment: I have already tried your solution in 'onCompleted' callback. As I said, it throws an error `form group expects ....`. It is working in my way, but I am asking that is there any better solution to this problem? @rashfmnb

Answer (score 0):

I have it working in rc5 but im not using the REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES directive anymore. In my Shared.Module.ts I import and export ReactiveFormsModule. Please let me know if it fixes your problem or you need more help.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, ...],
    declarations: [...],
    exports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, ...]
})
```